# Confirm Modal box appears twice

Tags: jquery, symfony

I am going crazy with this issue. This is my code

```
<form class="borrarGrupos" id="borrarGrupos" action="{{ path('grupo_delete_group', {'id_escuela': escuela.id }) }}" method="post">

....

<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Borrar Grupos marcados" />
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".borrarGrupos").click(function(ev) {
        $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">ATENCIÓN!! ¿Está seguro que quiere borrar el grupo?</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button><a class="btn btn-danger" id="dataConfirmOK">Quiero borrar el grupo</a></div></div>');
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text('¿Estás seguro de querer hacer esto?');
        $('#dataConfirmOK').click(function() {
            $(".borrarGrupos").submit();
        });
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```

If I submit the form and press cancel button at the first time and after I submit another time the form, this modal box appears two times. I dont know what is happening. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because your click function is triggered by the form, and because you have multiple "btn-danger"'s. Add an id="submit" to your submit button and change the trigger the below:

```
$("#submit").click(function(ev) {

//...

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure but your are telling me this $(".btn btn-danger").click(function(ev) {
       .......
    });

Comment: It doesn't work. The trigger $(".btn btn-danger").click(function(ev) { doesn't catch it :(

Comment: That is because there is a space, change ".btn btn-danger" to ".btn-danger"

Comment: Continue showing two modals boxes. Just changed btn btn-danger" to ".btn-danger". Thanks for your help

Comment: This is because you have multiple "btn-danger"'s.  Your submit button needs to have a unique ID.  Add an id="submit" to your submit button and then set the trigger to "#submit"

Comment: I think it could be because I use $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" This code is added each time I click the button and the second time exists in the code two times and I tried with this code $('#dataConfirmCANCEL').click(function() {
    $('#dataConfirmModal').remove();
    
      }); It behaviour is correct but the screen set gray ...